# How to convert array to json and bind the json data in a table in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of,

[image]

I am trying to convert that to a JSON , so I can bind the data in a bootstrap table like this,

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";

function Home() {
 
  const customers = [
    {
      CustomerId: 1,
      Name: "John Hammond",
      Country: "United States",
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 2,
      Name: "Mudassar Khan",
      Country: "India",
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 3,
      Name: "Suzanne Mathews",
      Country: "France",
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 4,
      Name: "Robert Schidner",
      Country: "Russia",
    },
  ];

  

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12">
          <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>File Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {customers.map(customers=>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{customers.Name}</td>
                        <td>{customers.Country}</td>
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Like in this example, they are binding Name and country from customers, I want to bind path data and mode data from the array and bind to the table.

I tried JSON.stringify but it is not working. How to do this?

This is the full code

```html
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
import { Octokit } from "octokit";

function Home() {
  getContents();
  let jsonString = '';
  const customers = [
    {
      CustomerId: 1,
      Name: "John Hammond",
      Country: "United States",
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 2,
      Name: "Mudassar Khan",
      Country: "India",
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 3,
      Name: "Suzanne Mathews",
      Country: "France",
    },
    {
      CustomerId: 4,
      Name: "Robert Schidner",
      Country: "Russia",
    },
  ];
  let contentResponse = "";
  let valueArray = [];
  async function getContents() {
    try {
      return await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          const octokit = new Octokit({
            auth: "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",
          });
          const response = await octokit.request(
            "GET /repos/KaranS0406/React/git/trees/4c1289a6405a5d87de6f1071ce723ee8b94be276?recursive=1"
          );
          console.log(response.data.tree);
          contentResponse = response.data.tree;
          Object.entries(contentResponse).forEach((element) => {
            const [key, value] = element;
            valueArray.push(value);
          });
          resolve("success");
        } catch (error) {
          reject("error");
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12">
          <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>File Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {customers.map(customers=>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{customers.Name}</td>
                        <td>{customers.Country}</td>
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: response.data.tree is the JSON object am getting.

Comment: you want path inside name and mode inside country is that correct.?

Comment: Yes path in the place of name and mode in the place of country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this after contentResponse line and check with console.log if is that what do you want.?

```js
const convertdata = contentResponse.map((item) =>{
    let obj={
      Name:item.path,
      Country:item.mode
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by what you get in the console, you already have what you need, just replace `customers` with your array (`response.data.tree`) and replace also `name` and `country` with `path` and `mode`.

```
{myArray.map(element =>
    <tr>
        <td>{element.path}</td>
        <td>{element.mode}</td>
    </tr>
)}
```

Comment: But I tried mapping contentresponse it is showing contentresponse is not a map function

Comment: Myabe the problem here is that you are calling `getContents` asynchronously, try `await getContents();` in your first line.

Comment: I agree with @Javito the problem is with how you have defined the function